# user login with ROPC flow with AAD

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

When using ROPC flow with AAD does the invited user share the same credentials (username, password) which he must be using on other AAD tenant\MS account.

I see that ROPC is not a recommended flow as our client should not handle the credentials. But just wanted to know what we are compromising other then training user for Phishing sites and loosing some important features like MFA etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

e. g if I have my account in Parent Azure directory (A) and I am invited guest\member in Azure directory (B). Then for the Enterprise SPA App (whichever directory it belongs to) user using ROPC flow will use the same username, password for login into the app. This would compromise both the Azure account if the credentials are hacked. So is there a way when we invite user they should not be associated with existing Azure directory (i.e A or B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there a way when we invite user they should not be associated
> with existing Azure directory (i.e A or B)?

In short, **NO**.

When you choose ROPC flow, it means you need to take the risks. Whether you use ROPC flow in your own tenant or in another tenant, your credentials are at risk of leakage.

Therefore, if you are worried about this, choosing an alternative authentication flow is your first choice.

I assume that you simply do not want to log in interactively, then you can consider [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), which can easily access the data in both Tenant A and B.

Comment: Thanks @Allen Wu this is what I was looking for. From you answer I see that the users are very tightly coupled with AAD tenants\active directories. Can you share any link to support the NO answer.

Comment: Actually, we do want to login interactively through web SPA client. But after some research looks like the complete customization for UI is something which is not possible with AAD B2B and B2C (Mostly looks like due to users tight coupling with multiple accounts). So was trying to find out low risk alternatives to achieve it.

Comment: @Santan I don't have an official document which supports the NO answer. If this idea is not supported and uncommon, I believe Microsoft doesn't provide a document to state it. It's based on my experience on AAD. Although your account is a B2B user in tenant B, you can still sign in with [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) easily. Why do you mention "complete customization for UI"? I don't think it will effect on how you sign in.

Comment: Yes B2B does support "customizing the UI" but they don't allow to change the domain which is something like https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com. We want the domain to be custom. [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains). Many other flow around authentication and user management such as Signup, Forgot password, Reset password, Update profile etc we wanted it to have custom UI with custom domain, but B2B does not provide that flexibility.

Comment: Currently we are on B2C with implicit flow (will move to PKCE for security) but it has very limited customization options.

Answer (score 0):

One major concern is already that you have mentioned. The Client is handling the credentials. There will be high trust that needs to be put on the client.

In addition to the above mentioned, the below points might be in consideration for you that I could think of :

1. On using the ROPC grant type, there is no way to distinguish if the resource owner (the user) is really making that request or the client is making the request.
2. Federated identity is also unavailable to this grant type
3. Not applicable for the Live Accounts (@outlook.com,@hotmail.com etc)
4. SSO is also not feasible.
5. If you are hashing and storing the password locally, if there is a password expiry - then this will fail.

Comment: Thanks Satya for the reply. My question was around the username, password across multiple AAD accounts.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate a bit ? I was talking about the article you had shared ROPC Grant

Comment: Sorry, hit enter by mistake. Thanks @Satya V for the reply. My question was around the username, password across multiple AAD accounts. e. g if I have my account in Parent Azure directory (A) and I am guest\member in Azure directory (B). Then for the Enterprise SPA App user using ROPC flow will use the same username, password for login into the app. This would compromise both the Azure account if the credentials are hacked. So is there a way when we invite user they should not be associated with existing Azure directory (i.e A or B).

Comment: When you invite a user - user will be created in your tenant... I m not sure whether I got your question correct though

Comment: You are right about user getting created in my tenant when invited. But the username, password which are used in the SPA app are same as the username, password used for login to Active directory on multiple azure portal account. So wanted to prevent that. if we try using ROPC that would compromise the credentials for all accounts.

Comment: Unfortunately, No.. it is not possible !